# (De)Encoding a string In C

Tags: arrays, c, binary

I'm newcomer, and I want to make a program that converts the whole sentence into binary code. I have a main

```
int main(){
char* text = "Hello, how are you?";
const int len = strlen(text);
bool bytes1[len+1][8];
encode_string(text, bytes1);
for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++){
printf("%c: ", text[j]);
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    printf("%d", bytes1[j][i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
}
```

And i have a function `void encode_string(const char string[], bool bytes[strlen(string)+1][8])`

I wrote the code, but it gives me something that is not clear.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void encode_string(const char string[], bool bytes[strlen(string)+1][8]){
int len = strlen(string);
for(int t = len; t <= 0; t--){
    printf("%c: ", string[t]);
    for(int q = 0; q <= 7; q++){
        printf("%d", (q << string[t]) & 1 ? 1 : 0);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

this is what i get:

```
H: 192900192900
e: 192900192900
l: 192900192900
l: 192900192900
o: 192900192900
,: 192900192900
 : 192900192900
h: 192900192900
o: 00000000
w: 010064000
 : 000064000
a: 02000400
r: 00000000
e: 00000000
 : 00000000
y: 00000000
o: 00000000
u: 00000000
?: 00000000
 : 164342082441228500
```

but i can't figure out why

(bytes1 = bytes because we are throwing into the encode_string function)

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: Please tell your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) when and where you initialize the array `bytes1`.

Comment: If `t` is equal to `len`, then it's not `<= 0` unless the string is empty.

Comment: Also explain to your rubber duck the loop `for(int t = len; t <= 0; t--)`. And think about if you really want to include the null-terminator in your encoding.

Comment: On a different note: Don't over-include header files. The `encode_string` function only needs declarations from `<string.h>`, `<stdio.h>` and `<stdbool.h>`. The other two header files will only make your compile-time longer (not by much, but still).

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, all variables in C including text is already in binary form, so there's no need to convert anything. All we need to do is just to display the binary in whatever form that's considered convenient to the human reader.

For example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void)
{
  const char* text = "Hello, how are you?";
  size_t length = strlen(text);
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<length; i++)
  {
    for(size_t bit=0; bit<CHAR_BIT; bit++)
    {
      unsigned int bitmask = 1u << (CHAR_BIT-bit-1) ;
      printf("%u", (text[i] & bitmask) > 0);
    }
    printf(" = '%c'\n", text[i]);
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- `CHAR_BIT` is the pedantic way to write 8, since some rare and exotic systems need not necessarily have 8 bit bytes.
- The inner loop counts from bit 0 to 7. However, when printing binary we actually want to start with the MSB. Hence compensate the bit shift `CHAR_BIT-bit` to mask out bits starting with MSB. And compensate with `CHAR_BIT-bit-1` since we want to mask bit 7 to 0, not 8 to 1.
- `text[i] & bitmask` gives zero or non-zero if the bit is set. To convert this to boolean form, or rather an integer of value 1 or 0, compare the result with `> 0` to get either 1 or 0.

Output:

```
01001000 = 'H'
01100101 = 'e'
01101100 = 'l'
01101100 = 'l'
01101111 = 'o'
00101100 = ','
00100000 = ' '
01101000 = 'h'
01101111 = 'o'
01110111 = 'w'
00100000 = ' '
01100001 = 'a'
01110010 = 'r'
01100101 = 'e'
00100000 = ' '
01111001 = 'y'
01101111 = 'o'
01110101 = 'u'
00111111 = '?'
```